# OpenCV algorithm to determine true color (black, white, grey) of black and white scanned image?

Tags: image, opencv, colors

I'm working on a small program in OpenCV that can automatically clean scanned manga pages. Here are the theoretical before and afters:

Before:
http://raw.senmanga.com/Bleach/541/7/

After:
http://mangastream.com/read/bleach/26534422/10

The cleaned image in the second link was done manually in photoshop.

As you can see, I only have to work in black, white, and grey, but a comparison between the raw and the finished images shows that some pixels on the scanned image, although supposed to be black are actually returned as white by the scanner. I was thinking perhaps I could draw on information from the surrounding pixels as well in order to determine true color of a pixel, but before I work on this idea, I was wondering if there are any algorithms already that can do this true color determination for me? I cannot find a better scanner, so a hardware improvement is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your 8bit depth image

Apply grayscale (if its not already) and [histogram equalization](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) first.

Then apply low pass filter (gaussian blur) to reduce noises.

You may think of some type of cluster filtering instead of blurring, if you want to. Idea is this: Create a window and search the whole image starting from top left, set all the pixels inside window to black, if there is enough black pixels inside window.

Then group your pixels as such:

Group 1: pixels having gray <5

Group 2: pixels having 5< gray<250

Group 3: pixels having 250< gray

Take back your non-blurred image (image after histogram equalization),

Group 1 - write 0

Group 2 - write 127

Group 3 - write 255

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to comment because the original image cannot be displayed, but I guess scanning at higher resolution and applying median filter can get rid of smaller patches.

You can also check [Image Inpainting functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html), they are used for fixing this type of problems.